# I have played a song when power connected, but it's not stopping when power is disconnected

Tags: java, android

I want to play a song when the power is connected, and stop the song when the power is disconnected, but this song still plays when the power is disconnected. Please share working code regarding this.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  public MyReceiver() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving

    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.mysong);

    if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) {
      mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
      mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
      mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
    else if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "POWER DISCONNECTED !!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      mMediaPlayer.stop();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Does the line `mMediaPlayer.stop();` get called when the power is disconnected?

Comment: mMediaPlayer.stop();Toast.makeText(context, "POWER DISCONNECTED !!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   im getting this toast..im running in my device

Answer (score 0):

This Link will help you.
You have to register Broadcast for android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED.
and than receive on of power disconnect broadcast stop you media player.

https://techcampuz.blogspot.in/2016/07/how-to-detect-when-power-connected-and.html

And your above code for every broadcast message Mediaplayer created new object so that me be problem, user that outside of the receiver method.